# cast an array of enum to pointer of int

Tags: c++, static-cast

I'm getting the complaint from complier when trying to convert a array of enum to an pointer of int.

```
void format(const int *values);
// convert and call format
format(static_cast<const int*>(EnumArray));

// error from compiler
error: invalid static_cast from type 'const EnumArray[15]' to type 'const int*'
```

Any way to get around it? Thanks!

Comment: I guess you have to provide a conversion from `EnumArray` to `int*`. How else should the compiler know what to do?

Comment: You can not convert `enum array` to `const int *`. First of all their types are different and even their size are not guaranteed to be same.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`, if you're feeling lucky. Use compatible types if you want to fix it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I can solve it with template. It compiles and runs.

```
    template<typename T>
    String8  format(const T *values)
    {
          //use values as array of int
          int v = values[i];
    }

    //call it
    format(EnumArray); // no type needed since it can be deduced
```

Comment: You use `values` as array of `T`, but  `values[i]` (`T`) is convertible to `int`. You would have to explicitly convert to `int` if you used an `enum class`.

Answer (score 1):

If you exactly know what you are doing, you can use `reinterpret_cast`.

```
format(reinterpret_cast<const int*>(EnumArray));
```

Comment: I would add a `static_assert(std::is_same<int, std::underlying_type<Enum>::type>::value, "Invalid underlying type of enum");` in that case.